# Google Maps Marker -- Drag & Drop Marker onto a Flutter Image?

Tags: image, flutter, maps, marker

I'm using Google Maps for Flutter but Google Maps for Android is close enough.

**I want to place fixed Flutter image overtop the map (positioned with Stack) then be able to drag & drop a map marker onto that image for an event on that image?**

Is that possible?  I'm aware of displaying Google Maps in Flutter, displaying the Flutter image overtop the map, and dragging a marker.  What i can't figure out is how to trigger an event once the marker is dropped on the Flutter image.  I figure this involves converting the dropped marker's latlng to screen coordinates and knowing what my flutter image's screen coordinates each time the screen orientation changes.

Comment: Do you really need google maps for this? Or you just need drag 'n drop functionality?

Comment: I need to use Google Maps.

Comment: Did you find out any solution to this?